# How to search a text using entity framework after split?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have a entity model

```
public class User{
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
   public string Department {get;set;}
}
```

So I want to search a text like `"john smith"` in database using entity framework core 3.1.

I am splitting the text before.

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<UserListViewModel>> Search(string search)
    {
        var terms = search.Split(" ");

        var queryable = _context.Users.Where(s => terms.All(m => s.Department.ToLower().Contains(m)) ||
                                                  terms.All(m => s.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(m)) ||
                                                  terms.All(m => s.LastName.ToLower().Contains(m))).AsQueryable();

        ...........
        ...........
        ...........
    }
```

but does it not work.

So how can I do it?

Comment: Do it vice versa something like `s => terms.Contains(s.Department.ToLower())` etc.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy I don't think that will be as helpful - imagine the search string is "j smith tech" and you are trying to find "John Smith" in the "Information Technology" department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core 3.x doesn't really support translation of `All` and `Any` in most cases, and your code is slightly wrong, I think what you really want is:

```
var queryable = _context.Users.Where(u => terms.All(m => u.Department.Contains(m) ||
                                                         u.FirstName.Contains(m) ||
                                                         u.LastName.Contains(m)));
```

Since this can't be translated, you need to reformat it into code that can.

With [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) you can use `PredicateBuilder` to create an extension that will remap the query into a series of `&&` tests for each term:

```
// searchTerms - IEnumerable<TKey> where all must be in a row's key
// testFne(row,searchTerm) - test one of searchTerms against a row
// dbq.Where(r => searchTerms.All(s => testFne(r,s)))
public static IQueryable<T> WhereAll<T,TKey>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, IEnumerable<TKey> searchTerms, Expression<Func<T, TKey, bool>> testFne) {
    var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
    foreach (var s in searchTerms)
        pred = pred.And(r => testFne.Invoke(r, s));

    return dbq.Where((Expression<Func<T,bool>>)pred.Expand());
}
```

which you would use like:

```
var queryable = _context.Users
                    .WhereAll(terms,
                              (u,m) => u.Department.Contains(m) ||
                                       u.FirstName.Contains(m) ||
                                       u.LastName.Contains(m));
```

For "john smith", the extension method would create the equivalent of:

```
var queryable = _context.Users
                    .Where(u => (u.Department.Contains("john") ||
                                 u.FirstName.Contains("john") ||
                                 u.LastName.Contains("john")) &&
                                (u.Department.Contains("smith") ||
                                 u.FirstName.Contains("smith") ||
                                 u.LastName.Contains("smith"))
                           );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need `terms.All`. as "john smith" is a full name **all** of it is not gonna be found in a first or last name field.

I'm not sure if the following is possible.

```
var queryable = _context.Users.Where(s => terms.Contains(m => s.Department.ToLower().Contains(m)) &&
                                                  terms.Contains(m => s.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(m)) ||
                                                  terms.All(m => s.LastName.ToLower().Contains(m))).AsQueryable();
```

Though it's not quite accurate, it'd return "john john" as well this way, but it's rare.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following.

```
  void Main()
  {
    var users = new List<User>
    {
        new User { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith", Department = "Web" },
        new User { FirstName = "Aaliyah", LastName = "Lin", Department = "Warehouse" },
        new User { FirstName = "Cristian", LastName = "Stone", Department = "Cleaning" },
        new User { FirstName = "Kierra", LastName = "Davidson", Department = "Mobile" },
        new User { FirstName = "Lizbeth", LastName = "Gregory", Department = "Web" }
    };
    
    var search = "Lizbeth Gregory";
    var terms = search.ToLower().Split(' ');
    users.Where(s => terms.All(m => s.Department.ToLower().Contains(m)) ||
                                                      (terms.Any(m => s.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(m))) ||
                                                      terms.Any(m => s.LastName.ToLower().Contains(m)))
                                                      .Dump();
}

public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I assume the issue is EF Core 3.1 won't translate `All` or `Any` in most useful cases.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to aggregate your search terms:

```
var terms = search
    .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
query = terms
    .Aggregate(query, (current, term) =>
         current.Where(x =>
             x.FirstName.Contains(term)
             || x.LastName.Contains(term)
             || x.Department.Contains(term)
         )
    );
```